# Add conditional stylesheet into the Drupal's Chameleon theme

Tags: drupal, conditional-statements, stylesheet

This is really urgent. I need to add a conditional stylesheet for IE6. However, in the chameleon theme there isn't any page.tpl. I download the conditional stylesheet module but it doesn;t work.

I'm using Drupal 6 btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got it.

go to chameleon.theme. insert 
`$output .= '<!--[if IE 6]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/themes/chameleon/ie6.css" /> 
<![endif]-->';`

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in info file of theme, like this:
`conditional-stylesheets[if IE][all][] = ie.css`
see Zen theme for example

Or can use manual embedding, see garland theme:

```
  <head>
<?php print $head ?>
<title><?php print $head_title ?></title>
<?php print $styles ?>
<?php print $scripts ?>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
  <?php print phptemplate_get_ie_styles(); ?>
<![endif]-->
```

phptemplate_get_ie_styles defined in template.php of these file.

Comment: This is only a zen theme feature and a Drupal feature. Since the OP is using Chameleon theme, this wont help.